# First page with QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

How to load index page with QueryString in asp.net? I know that we can redirect to a particular page with QueryString, but what I want is to load first page with some querystring.

Comment: How you load the application first in browser? with query string?

Comment: Why do you need that? You can always provide default values in your code when you parse query string and there is no query string at all.

Comment: http://localhost:22609/index.aspx is my first page. When I view it in browser it works, but I want to load this index page with some querystring such as http://localhost:22609/index.aspx?a=22.

Comment: The QueryString is read-only. You need your users to add it themselves, or not rely on it in your index page (since it's an index page, there's no reason to expect a QueryString anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are setting start action in Property pages of your application then you can follow following steps

1) right click on your project in solution explores
2) Go to Property pages
3) Set start action to 'Specific Page' and `value = "index.aspx?a=22"`

Comment: Thanks. It works on my local computer. How do I do when I upload it on IIS Server?

Comment: You can't. This is a setting for Visual Studio debugging, there's no way to force something like this from IIS. All this does is change what URL Visual Studio uses when you press debug.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to make it work on both local and remote enviroments is to, at `page_load()`, detect if the desired QueryString content is present.

If not, Use `Response.Redirect` pointing to the current page with the added QueryString parameters. Example follows:

```
if (Request.QueryString["QSEntry"] == null)
    Response.Redirect("Page.aspx?QSEntry=desiredValue");
```

- Pro: It'll work the way you want.
- Con: You're actually loading the page twice (first time it's a parameterless load), so don't forget to take that into consideration.